# How to restore my mouse pointer when it unvisible with QWSSERVER::SetCursorVisible(false)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm

I have an application in Qt. I want to hide the cursor shape for my app on tiny6410(Friendly Arm Linux device). I use this code with this [reference](https://forum.qt.io/topic/7524/hide-mouse-pointer/5) :

```
#include <QWSServer>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
#ifdef Q_WS_QWS
QWSServer::setCursorVisible( false );
#endif
```

after that when I run my program with this command : `./VS200 -qws` it is running and the pointer does not show **BUT , the screen touch is also not work**.
When I change the `false` to `true` it shows the pointer but when i touch the screen to press button the mouse shape is disappear and the touch is not work.
How can I solve this problem by changing the setting?
How `QWSSERVER::SetCursorVisible` change the Linux setting?

---

**NOTE**:When I write this command "cat /dev/touchscreen-1wire" the touch is worked
but when the Qt application is run, touch does not work.

This QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=TSLIB:/dev/touchscreen-1wire. and the tslib is setting
on this config.

Comment: Is there any one to help me?

Answer (score 1):

the mouse is QT to draw out, when QT is started by the environment variable export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO="TPanel:/dev/input/event0 USB:/dev/input/mice",

Introduced into mouse device file (touch screen, mouse USB:/dev/input/mice), QT real-time access to this device file, access to relevant events are handled and constantly redraw the mouse.

Comment: thanks for reply. but when I test the other device with `cat` command. they did not worked.